Powershell - Create new registry key and add values
I am trying to create a registry key "ABCProxy" for an application say "Pricer"
then I want add parameters and values to the key Enable x3 and RetryAttemptsx5
Define the path to the registry key
$registryPath = 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\OurC\Pricer\Application\ABCProxy'

Create the registry key
New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force

Set a new value within the recreated registry key
{New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "Enable" -Value "3" -PropertyType "Reg_DWORD"}
{New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "RetryAttempts" -Value "5" -PropertyType "Reg_DWORD"}

Verify the change
{Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath}


What is your question?

Oh hi, I am just wondering if this script is correct or not

Have you tried it?

$registryPath should be 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\OurC\Pricer\Application\ABCProxy' or 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\OurC\Pricer\Application\ABCProxy' and why do you wrap the New-ItemProperty and Get-ItemProperty lines inside curly braces (to make them script blocks) ??

Also, REG_DWORD means a 32-bit number, so you can omit the quotes around the values

hklm:\software not hklm\software, dword not reg_dword
